# How to redirect to customer account login page using Ajax in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, login, ajax, redirect

I have created a custom module for **adding product to wishlist using ajax**. In my custom module controller I have checked the user is login or not, **if not logged in and trying to add to wishlist it won't redirect to customer account login page** because of it appending the current module route id before it. How to resolve this issue?
Please solve this issue asap possible.

Add.php

```
<?php
namespace WeltPixel\Quickview\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
class Add extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_wishlistRepository;

    protected $_productRepository;
    //protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    protected $response;

    // public function __construct(
    //     \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistRepository,
    //     \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    // ) {
    //     $this->_wishlistRepository= $wishlistRepository;
    //     $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    // }
    public function __construct(
        //Session $customerSession,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        Validator $formKeyValidator
    ) {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
         $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
         $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
         $this->_wishlistRepository= $wishlistRepository;
         $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {  

      $productData = $this->getRequest()->getparam('product');

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

        $customerId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        //echo $customerId;die;
        $wishlist = $this->_wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);

        $wishlist->addNewItem($productData);
        $wishlist->save();
        echo "success";
        return;

    }else{      
            //$response['errors'] = true;
            //$response['message'] = 'Error Here';
            //$this->_redirect('customer/account/login');
            //$response = $this->_url->getUrl('customer/account/login');            
            // return;
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
            //$resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
            //  $resultJson->setData(['url'=>$response]);                         
            //  echo $response;
             // return $response;
  //           exit();
        // return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setUrl(rm_request('customer/account/login/'));
        // echo "hiee";die;
        // $redirect = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http');
        // $redirect->setRedirect('../../customer/account/login/');
     //    return $redirect;
    }


    }
}

?>
```

customwishlist.phtml

```
<?php
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); //instance of\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager
$storeManager = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
$baseUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl();
$topCollection = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$TopProductcollection = $topCollection->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        //->addAttributeToFilter('status', '1')
        //->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock',['eq' => 1])
        //->setOrder('position', 'DESC')
        //->setPageSize(6)
        //->setCurPage(1)
        ->load();

        foreach ($TopProductcollection as $collection) {
            $products = $collection->getData();
                //print_r($products);
                echo $products['entity_id'];
                ?>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="ajaxWishUrl('<?php echo $products['entity_id'] ?>')">wishlist</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="compareProductUrl('<?php echo $products['entity_id'] ?>')"> compare</a>

      <?php   }


$FormKey = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey');
?>
<!--  <span id="cartLoader" style="display:none"><img src="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>ajax-loader.gif"  width="30" height="30"></span> -->
<script type="text/javascript">    


/*Top Selling Compare*/ 
    function compareProductUrl(id) {
        //jQuery("#cartLoader").fadeIn();
        var form_key = '<?php echo $FormKey->getFormKey(); ?>';
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'product=' + id + '&form_key=' + form_key,
            url: "<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>catalog/product_compare/add",
            success: function(data) {
               // jQuery("#cartLoader").fadeOut();
            }
        });
    }

/*Top Selling Wishlist*/

    function ajaxWishUrl(id) {
        ///jQuery("#cartLoader").fadeIn();
        var form_key = '<?php echo $FormKey->getFormKey(); ?>';
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'product=' + id + '&form_key=' + form_key,
            url: "<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>weltpixel_quickview/index/add",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
        //              if (data.redirectUrl) {
        //                 window.location.href = response.redirectUrl;
        //             }
        // alert("succc");
                //jQuery("#cartLoader1").fadeOut();
            }
        });
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code please.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, however, I try to answer your question in general way.

Comment: yeah i have update my code

Comment: please check if there any wrong?

Comment: and please check the else session of execute function

Comment: i have commented all the code please check those too

Comment: if you have any custom module for that please send the code link as we need asap..

Comment: @MandarParbate you should try my answer. You can see how to use Json response.

Comment: yep, Got the result. Thnx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can set the redirect url in our ajax response.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Customer\Controller\Ajax;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Wishlist extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * Wishlist constructor.
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $response = [
            'errors' => false,
            'message' => __('Added Item successful.')
        ];
        //If not not login and check isXml Http request(Ajax)
        if(!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn() && !$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $response['errors'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Error Here';
            $response['redirectUrl'] = $this->_url->getUrl('controller/you/want');
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
            $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
            $resultJson->setData($response);

        }
        //Logic for customer login here
    }
}
```

In our Ajax function, we need to check the return url

```
 if (response.redirectUrl) {
         window.location.href = response.redirectUrl;
 }
```

We can see more:

> - vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Ajax/Login.php
> - vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/action/login.js